# How to calculate the output from this neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[image]
bias w0=0.15 and w01=0.5. Assume the intercept of the combination function is 0.

Basically, I am studying for my exam and I don't understand how to calculate this question about neural network:

1) the output of H1 and H2

2) the output of node 1.

Thank you.

Comment: i followed this video its very simple: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK-yg4D_elE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows are weights, the nodes store values. You multiply the values by weights. So if you take the part of a graf:

```
              b
x[0] - w[0] \ |
x[1] - w[1] - h 
x[2] - w[2] /
```

it means `h = x[0]w[0] + x[1]w[1] + x[2]w[2] + b`, where `b` is bias term. So basically, `h` is a result of dot product between vector of values and a vector of weights.

Comment: so basically h1 is 0.5x0.1+0.1x0.3+0.3x0.25=.155
h2 is 0.5x0.2+0.1x0.15+0.3x0.11=.148

node 1=.155x.1+.148x.4=.2142?

Comment: @Kenny yes unless there are activation functions that you didn't mention

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention "bias w0=0.15 and w01=0.5. Assume the intercept of the combination function is 0."

Comment: ♦ sorry, i dont understand. could you try to apply it into one of the formula please?

Comment: So, the bias term is just for node 1?
And, there are 2 bias terms here. I add those 2 in node 1?

Comment: @Kenny you can add the bias term or not, if and where you add the bias term is your choice. You can think of it as additional node equal to 1 multiplied by some weight.